# Apple TV & computer itunes

Tags: home-sharing

I have a total of 119 movies on my Apple tv. I have homesharing on. When I log into my itunes on my computer it only shows a total of 40 movies, where are the remaining missing movies?

Comment: With this amount of detail it sounds more like you need to contact iTunes Store support.

Comment: where do you have this movies on you apple tv? are this itunes purcheses?

Comment: Do you have show iCloud purchases enabled in your Preferences -> Store settings?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this might have to do with iTunes in the Cloud.

iTunes has the ability to show you everything that is stored locally, or show you everything you've ever purchased from the iTunes store.

From the VIEW menu click "Show Movies in the Cloud". This will make sure you're seeing everything you own.

Alternatively you might have your iTunes set to only show un-watched movies. Make sure that you're not in the "unwatched" view.

The new Apple TVs have no real internal storage so if you're seeing stuff on the Apple TV it either means it's on your machine or in the cloud.